# Using php to display image from url stored in Mysql database in jquery autocorrect

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, image

The title is a bit confusing I guess but this is what I need:

I have a jquery autocomplete textfield and it gets its data from a database.
Everything works, I can type a part of a zipcode in the textfield and when that part exists in the database it shows all available options together with the city, state etc.

But what I want is to show the flag of the country (as an image) in the list of options.
I made a new row: county (which contains the url to an image file of the flag)

And this is where it goes wrong:

---

```
$rs = mysql_query('select zip, city, county, state from zipcode where zip like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by zip asc limit 0,10', $dblink);

$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) )
{
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{


    $data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['zip'] .', '. $row['city'] .' '. $row['state'] .' '. <img src='http://www.colinch.com/fut/$row['county'].'' />  ,
        'value' => $row['zip']
    );
}
}
```

---

I'm not a php expert so I think it's just a simple thing that went wrong. When I remove the < img src="......." part it will just print the $row['county'] which looks like this: USA.png

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use a good text editor that color codes for you depending on the language. NotePad++ is a good free one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! and I also think a lot of people want to know how to do a similar thing like this so I hope this will help for them

Comment: also for your case, check out [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, I'm not good with php yet so what would be an alternative thing to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Quotes are totally wrong:

```
    'label' => $row['zip'] .', '. $row['city'] .' '. $row['state'] .'<img src=\'http://www.colinch.com/fut/'.$row['county'].'\' />',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['zip'] .', '. $row['city'] .' '. $row['state'] .' <img src="http://www.colinch.com/fut/'.$row['county'].'" />'  ,
        'value' => $row['zip']
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['zip'] .', '. $row['city'] .' '. $row['state'] .' '. '<img src="http://www.colinch.com/fut/'.$row['county'].'"'.'/>'  ,
        'value' => $row['zip']
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put the quotes in a wrong way. That's why the syntax highlighters are so helpful. Take a look at the code you wrote in your question. It got marked by SO and dark red / brown colors mark where the text is. You want `<img...` to be put into a text! Or even better, if possible, echo the stuff directly into html like so:

```
foreach($countries as $code)
{
    ?><img src="<?php echo $flag; ?>.png/><?php
}
```

If you decide that you don't want to / cannot do it this way then your code should look like this:

```
'label' => $row['zip'] .', '. $row['city'] .' '. $row['state'] .' <img src=\'http://www.colinch.com/fut/'.$row['county'].'\' />'
```

**P.S.** I would advise using `"` for html quotes and `'` for php quotes. This way you will not need any escaping :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to read

```
$data[] = array(
        'label' => "{$row['zip']}, {$row['city']} {$row['state']} <img src='http://www.colinch.com/fut/{$row['county']}' />"  ,
        'value' => $row['zip']
    );
```

The use of double quotes allows you to evaluate the variables used without escaping the string.

Your issue lies with your quoting method

```
.' '. <img src='http://www.colinch.com/fut/$row['county'].'' />
    ^--no start^--start                         ^--closed
```

You wanted to continue to build the string but did not include `<img` in the text. PHP then decided to continue again at `'http...`. This is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! What do you think is the best way to style the image a bit more?

Comment: style the code for it or style how the browser will display it?

Comment: Yeah I mean how the browser displays it, so for example vertical-align for the image and things like that, should I write that in the php file or make a class with css?

Comment: that would be handled by the CSS class/style